# Maria db wont start | Failed to get D-Bus connection

Tags: centos7, mariadb

I try to start my mariadb but I am failing to start the maria db and I dont have any clue why.. I am running centos 7 with mariadb. It doenst start when I reboot, also when I use the cli to start it it says this:

```
    [root@localhost mariadb]#  systemctl start mariadb.service
    Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

And when I check the journal its giving me this error:

```
[root@localhost mariadb]# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Sun 2015-05-17 12:38:39 CEST, end at Sun 2015-05-17 13:51:37 CEST. --
May 17 13:45:10 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
May 17 13:51:35 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has begun starting up.
May 17 13:51:35 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[7079]: Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
May 17 13:51:35 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[7079]: Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
May 17 13:51:35 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[7107]: 150517 13:51:35 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
May 17 13:51:35 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[7107]: 150517 13:51:35 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
May 17 13:51:36 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[7107]: 150517 13:51:36 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
May 17 13:51:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 17 13:51:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
May 17 13:51:37 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
```

How can I fix the Failed to get D-Bus connection: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory error?

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed when with:

```
[root@localhost mariadb]# nano /etc/my.cnf
```

then I uncommented my pid-file

```
#pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
```

And then I restarted mariadb